# How to execute with /bin/false shell

Tags: linux, php, bash, shell, fastcgi

I am trying to setup per-user fastcgi scripts that will run each on a different port and with a different user. Here is example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BIND=127.0.0.1:9001
USER=user
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=10000
```

etc...

However, if I add user with /bin/false (which I want, since this is about to be something like shared hosting and I don't want users to have shell access), the script is run under 1001, 1002 'user' which, as my Google searches showed, might be a security hole. My question is: Is it possible to allow user(s) to execute shell scripts but disable them so they cannot log in via SSH?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DenyUsers` or `DenyGroups` settings in `sshd_config`.

Comment: Did try'd that.. However still having same problem. Side note: I can do 'su user' and execute shell and any other command, but still if I do 'ps aux' I see that command is running under 1002 user..

Comment: Which same problem? That they can't execute shell scripts, or that they can log in via SSH?

Comment: A problem with commands being executed as 1002 and not as actual user..

Comment: Even if you were to deny them ssh access, they could still execute shell scripts via the web tree. It's not difficult to make system calls within PHP

Comment: It is if you use Safe Mode or even something like SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, why would you need to have `/bin/false` as the shell of the user? Why not simply have `/bin/bash` as the shell, and `AllowGroups` or `DenyGroups` setting at `sshd_config`? This solves the ssh login problem. Without the rights to login via ssh, would the user have shell access?

Alternatively, you can have your user environment script set as the user's shell, and put the user `AllowGroups` or `DenyGroup` setting at `sshd_config`. Of course, your script must be a locked down script. This solves the user environment problem and the ssh login problem.

In other words, which problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to completely block a user from logging in remotely using PAM:

/etc/security/access.conf:

```
- : user : ALL EXCEPT LOCAL
```

Instead of a single user, you can use a group.
Details in `man access.conf`
Then it won't be necessary to set user shell to /bin/false.

Comment: wouldn't that also block SFTP access? (I want to allow this.. )

Comment: Yes, it will. If you want SFTP access and not SSH, you may consider using rssh. Here's an [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-linux-install-configure-rssh-shell.html). This seems like a topic for serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Try using /bin/true instead of /bin/false and see if that affects it.

/bin/false always returns a non-zero value, which can cause problems. /bin/true will work just like /bin/false, except that it returns zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but if you take away their shell, then no, they can't execute shell scripts.  It's not unusual to set a users shell to /sbin/nologin, but it will result in the same thing as setting the shell to false.

The most straight forward answer that was proposed was editing sshd_config and limiting shell access there.

Most other ways of limiting access are less obvious than just configuring the access protocol to deny them.